# How do i give an array new values if they meet wanted conditions in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing

So i have some values for an array. I want to use the new values assigned to the statikk_start array in the calculation for Rs, but i get a mismatch error when running the code. I know this has something to do with when the colIndex reaches statikk_start(2) because instead in having one values, there will be a range of values. What would be the best and easiset way of solving the problem so that all values for statikk_start(2), statikk_start(3) and statikk_start(4) should be looped through and Rs should be calculated for all the looped-through values.

```
    Dim p As Range
    Set p = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("B4:K27")

    Dim statikk_start As Variant
    statikk_start = Array(6, 10, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6, 10)
    statikk_start(2) = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("E4:E27")
    statikk_start(3) = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("H4:E27")
    statikk_start(4) = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("I4:I27")

    Dim Rs(1 To 7) As Variant
    For colIndex = 1 To 7
        Rs(colIndex) = 2 * p_max(1, colIndex) / statikk_start(colIndex - 1)
    Next colIndex
```

I tried using the select case object in vba, but could not come with a solution

Comment: p_max is a range:

    Dim p_max As Range
    Set p_max = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("S36:Y36")

Comment: You need an inner loop for the case when `colIndex - 1` equals 2, 3, or 4.